# Header and columns are not aligned when I am using DataTable Fixed Header

Tags: jquery, angular, datatables, angular-datatables

**I am using https://github.com/l-lin/angular-datatables plugin in my angular-4 project.**

***https://github.com/l-lin/angular-datatables/issues/1129***

I have used DataTable Fixed Header Extension by installing following packages:

**JS file**

npm install datatables.net-fixedHeader --save

**CSS file**

npm install datatables.net-fixedHeader-dt --save

**Typings**

npm install .net-fixedHeader --save-dev

and it is working.

But header is not getting aligned with column on scroll. I think this is fixedHeader column and header width calculation is not invoking (adjust() function).
Can anybody please suggest some solution here or please tell me how to invoke adjust() function on scroll?

**I have tried following:**

```
@HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event'])
    onResize(event){
        this.dataTableElement.dtInstance.then((dtInstance: DataTables.Api) => console.log(dtInstance));
        dtInstance.fixedHeader.adjust();// This line throwing error
    }
```

Or any alternative solution or plugin for datatable Angular-4?

Controller code:

```
import { Component, ViewChild, OnInit,HostListener, ChangeDetectionStrategy, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
import { DataTableDirective } from 'angular-datatables';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-data-table',
  templateUrl: './pocDataTable.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./pocDataTable.component.scss'],
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class PocDataTableComponent implements OnInit {
    @ViewChild(DataTableDirective)
    private dataTableElement: DataTableDirective;
    @HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event'])
    onResize(event){

        this.dataTableElement.dtInstance.then((dtInstance: DataTables.Api) => {
            console.log("Width: " + event.target);
            //this.ref.markForCheck();
        });
        //this.dataTableElement.dtInstance.then((dtInstance: DataTables.Api) => console.log(dtInstance.fixedHeader));
    }
// Data Table Config:
    dtOptions: any = {};
    reCalculate: any = {};
    pages:any;
    perPage: any;

   loadingIndicator:boolean = false;
   reorderable:boolean = true;

  //dtOptions: any = {};

  editing = {};
  temp = [];

  constructor(private ref: ChangeDetectorRef) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {

    // Data Table
    this.dtOptions = {
      ajax: '../../public/data/sample.txt',
      columns: [{
        title: 'ID',
        data: 'index'
      }, {
        title: 'Name',
        data: 'name'
      }, {
        title: 'Gender',
        data: 'gender'
      }, {
        title: 'Age',
        data: 'age'
      }, {
        title: 'Phone',
        data: 'phone'
      }, {
        title: 'Address',
        data: 'address'
      }, {
        title: 'Latitude',
        data: 'latitude'
      }, {
        title: 'Longitude',
        data: 'longitude'
      }],
      pagingType: 'full_numbers',
      stateSave: true,
        fixedHeader: true
    };

      this.reCalculate = {};

      this.pages = [
          10, 50,100,1000
      ];
      this.perPage = this.pages[0];
      //this.dtElement.dtInstance.then((dtInstance: DataTables.Api) => console.log(dtInstance));

  }
  }
```

Comment: please add your controller's code.

Comment: Hi @Irfan. Added controller code. Please have a look.